# Autobahn pubsub, queues and topics?

Tags: python, autobahn

The Autobahn documentation is a bit unclear on which/how clients receive messages once they are published. Out of the box it seems that a message is broadcast to all subscribers of a topic - they all get it. But is there any way to distribute a message to a single client? Something in the lines of a queue where multiple publishers add messages to a queue and messages are distributed to "free" subscribers, round robin style? Guess it can also be referred to as the Simple Pirate pattern.

Comment: Pubsub is intended to publish a particular event to which subscribers listen for. It sounds like what you want is more of a task queue with multiple workers.

Answer (score 1):

As noted normally publish goes to all subscribers.

If you want to publish and direct to a specific subscriber(s), then you direct with the eligible parameter.  Here is the WAMP doc:

http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.wamp.html?highlight=eligible#autobahn.wamp.message.Publish

```
class autobahn.wamp.message.Publish(request, topic, args=None, kwargs=None, acknowledge=None, excludeMe=None, exclude=None, eligible=None, discloseMe=None)
```

In your case you would need to provide the list of eligible session ids e.g. eligible = ( 1,2,3, )

I don't have a v2 example, but, judging by the source, I'd guess something like:

```
self.publish(u'com.myapp.topic1',  eligible = [100, 200, 300] )
```

In v1 I used this technique to publish to a subset of the subscribers.  In v2, I am using the subscription topic itself to limit who receives the message.  So, I might create com.pub.m1, com.pub.m2, com.pub.m3, etc instead of com.pub, and my clients subscribe to the topic which dictates what they will receive.